# How can I utilize external navigations for anythingslider in these demos to create previous next external controls

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

These are two resource examples for AnythingSlider

http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Cm479/4398/

http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Cm479/4401/

I require simple Previous/Next and pause play navigation but external for Anythingslider. Can anyone please help me out with this?

Kindest Regards,

Junaid

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty basic example ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Cm479/5106/)), but try this HTML

```
<div id="externalNav">
Goto <a href="#1">One</a> |
    <a href="#2">Two</a> |
    <a href="#3">Three</a> |
    <a href="#4">Four</a> |

    <a class="play" href="#play">Play</a>
</div>
```

and this script

```
var $s = $('#slider');

$s.anythingSlider({
    // If true, builds a list of anchor links to link to each panel
    buildNavigation: false,
    buildStartStop: false
});

// set up external links
$('#externalNav a').click(function(){
    // get slide number (ignore the #)
    var slide = $(this).attr('href').substring(1),
        // get AnythingSlider data object
        slider = $s.data('AnythingSlider');
    if (slide === "play") {
        // toggle slideshow
        slider.startStop( !slider.playing );
        // change link text
        $('a.play').text( slider.playing ? 'Pause' : 'Play' );
    } else {
        // go to selected slide
        $s.anythingSlider(slide);
    }
    // prevent link from changing the hash
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/ycUB6/982/

I think you can alter the `onInitialized` parameter/function to something like this:

```
onInitialized: function(e, slider) {
    $("a.next-slide").click(function(){
        slider.goForward();
    });
    $("a.prev-slide").click(function(){
        slider.goBack();
    });
}
```

Of course, you would use whatever classes/ids are on your next/prev links.